# How to return Arrays.asList() in ordered list<String>?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I don't know this is duplicate or not. If so, please share the link as I don't find anyone yet.
In my Java program, I have a String like following(String is created dynamically).

```
String header="Requirements ID,Requirements Number,Requirements Desc,Requirements Text,Requirements Date";
```

Now I am creating a List

```
List<String> csv = new ArrayList<String>(); 
csv=Arrays.asList(header.split("\\s*,\\s*")); //splittng each phrase separated by comma
```

But I am not getting List value in an unordered way. I mean I get the list value like this

```
[Requirements Number,Requirements Date,Requirements Desc,Requirements ID,Requirements Text]
```

I know list is unordered. But I want the list *csv* be like this

```
[Requirements ID,Requirements Number,Requirements Desc,Requirements Text,Requirements Date]
```

So my question is how to get this in ordered way? Any possible solution?

Comment: What is the definition of the ordering you are looking for?  It doesn't seem to be purely alphabetical/lexographical, which would be the usual definition of "sort".

Comment: Not alphabetical sorting. See how the string is. first is `Requiremtns ID` But in the list I am getting, first is `Requirements Number`. So how to get it the list as in exact order of the string value contents?

Comment: When I run your code, I get the output as `[Requirements ID,Requirements Number,Requirements Desc,Requirements Text,Requirements Date]` the one you expect.

Comment: But I am not getting like that.

Comment: Everything that implements the List interface is ordered, including ArrayList. The code example you have shown should work. Your code might be using a different variable with the name "header" which is causing this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use StringTokenizer

1.) Using **StringTokenizer**, split the string with the delimiter ","

2.) Iterate the StringTokenizer and fill the list

3.) Now while filling, it will happen in order

**pseudo code is something like**

```
String header="Requirements ID,Requirements Number,Requirements Desc,Requirements Text,Requirements Date";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(header,",") ;
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>() ;
while (st.hasNextToken()) {
  strList.add(st.nextToken()) ;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add a counter like `int count=0; strList.add(count,st.nextToken())` And increment the value of count in while loop?

Comment: Nope, not necessary, `while (st.hasNextToken())` will loop untill the last token

Comment: @Shiju K Babu : If you find this answer useful, Please mark this as correct answer ;) :)

Comment: In my eclispe, `hasNextToken()` not displaying. I am using java 6. is `hasMoreTokens()` ok?

Comment: ya `hasMoreTokens()` should be fine. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: OP's original code should work too. There is another still undiscovered  issue in OP's code causing the different ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use apache string utils and the collections api:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

```
    String header="Requirements ID,Requirements Number,Requirements Desc,Requirements Text,Requirements Date";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(header,","));
    Collections.sort(list);
```